# Java in Eclipse: Why must I always use a project?

Tags: eclipse, projects

I am just learning Java and use Eclipse. I have a question that I can not find an answer to.

Why does eclipse require me to use a project? I am using eclipse now to learn Java,
and that means compiling my source.

Problem being that when I add another source file Eclipse
compiles both applications. This means (and I could be very wrong here) I need to create a project
for every new program I write.

Why can I not just create and compile programs without a project?

Comment: You most definitely can. Open a command line, type `javac <source_file>.java`, profit.

Comment: Eclipse is built for enterprise applications, if you want to create and compile small solutions go with something more simplistic. Maybe http://www.drjava.org/

Answer (score 0):

What are you missing is called 'Run Configurations'.

1. Create a project.
2. Write your multiple programs within this one project.  (Presumably, these programs might share some class files or other resources.)
3. Each of your programs will contain a class file with an entry point, for example, a `main()` method.
4. Open this class file and right-click.  Select 'Run As', then the most appropriate option.

Following this you will see your Run Configurations here:

[image]

Click the drop-down icon and select the Run Configuration that you want to execute.  Select 'Run Configurations...' if you want to add program arguments or making other changes.